# warning: character constant too long for its type car.second = 'Sarim';

Tags: c++, data-structures, std-pair

I want to make a pair of int and string.
As:

```
pair<int,string> car ;
car.first = 10;
car.second = 'Sarim';
cout<<car.first<<endl;
cout<<car.second;
```

"sarim" is converted into 'm' in output?
[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages, please. Post code and errors as *text* directly *in* the question.

Comment: Okay, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
car.second = "Sarim";
```

The second of the pair is an `std::string`, not a character, hence you can provide an `std::string` or `const char*` to be used to construct one.

Note that the single quotes are for characters while the double ones I used make a `const char*` which can be used to construct an `std::string`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WTn9Kd)

Comment: An explanation for why.

Comment: Almost, that's on me for not explaining myself. Double quotes for string, single quotes for character is the explanation I think is needed.

Comment: It worked. Thanks, @asmmo Can you please describe it more?

Comment: Also side note, that the `car` can be constructed via `car = std::make_pair(10, "Sarim");`

Answer (score 2):

`r.second = 'Sarim';` is wrong. Single quotes are used for character constants and what you have there is *not* a single character.
You want

```
r.second = "Sarim";
```

for a multiple character literal.

Answer (score 1):

A *string* in C++ is marked using *double*-quotes (`"`), the *single* quotes mark a *character* (hence only one character is stored). The warning is here to tell you that your “character” is too big (and indeed since it's supposed to be a string).